# No setter/field for while trying to populate a listview on firebase

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am trying to retrieve data from firebase and display it on my listview using firebase-ui. The code runs fine but nothing is displayed on the list view. This is what I get from my logs:

> W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for -KNRXdDOlA9nV6qxXvOl found on class com.example.sammie.coreteccontacts.Sacco

Here is my FirebaselistAdapter

```
DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
FirebaseListAdapter<Sacco> adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Sacco>(getActivity(), Sacco.class, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mDatabaseReference) {
 @Override
protected void populateView(View view, Sacco sacco, int i) {
((TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(Sacco.getName());
}
};
contactList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here is my Sacco class:

```
package com.example.sammie.coreteccontacts;

public class Sacco {

    String description;
    String location;
    static String name;

    public Sacco() {
    }

    public Sacco(String description, String location, String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.location = location;
    }

    public static String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
}
```

Here is a sample of the data from firebase

> KNRWnG6BTkbGJQJVq9Qaddclose
>
> description:"test description"
>
> location: "test location"
>
> name: "test name"

Comment: you need to add setters for each variable inside `Sacco` class. e.g. `public void setDescription(String description){ this.description = description; }`. Also if `name` is unique to the object you probably don't want it to be `static`

Comment: I have added the setters but still get the same error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no setter methods in your class.

```
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}
```

**BUT**

> -KNRWnG6BTkbGJQJVq9Qaddclose

This is a unique key which is to be obtained as an object containing your description, location and name.

> W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for -KNRXdDOlA9nV6qxXvOl found on class
>   com.example.sammie.coreteccontacts.Sacco

This shows that there is an error with your database listener's positioning. It is reading `-KNRWnG6BTkbGJQJVq9Qaddclose` as a variable to your Sacco class instead of an object of it.

Please check the JSON file and DatabaseReference. Most probably it should be like this:

- UnderChilds **<-----** (ON CHILD LISTENER).

  - -KNRWnG6BTkbGJQJVq9Qaddclose
  - -KNRWnSYnuojkbGJQJVq9Qaddclos

Comment: Let me try this, I'll get back to you

Comment: I realised I was calling the getName() method on the Sacco class so I changed it to call the getName() on the sacco object
`((TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(sacco.getName());`
I added the setters methods to the Sacco class then changed the name variable to non static
But I still get the same error
how do I implement this
`This shows that there is an error with your database listener's positioning. It is reading -KNRWnG6BTkbGJQJVq9Qaddclose as a variable to your Sacco class instead of an object of it.`

Comment: Where are you adding the Database Listener, on which node? Also, please show the JSON structure for example

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9G2YgsHZohDc2l3dnFhcUxJd1U/view?usp=sharing)
Here is an overview of my JSON structure, I think the problem is how the data is structured, i think I'll have to implement a child listener after getting the database reference, could you please advice on that.

Comment: Yes, I checked your data. You should put `ChildEventListener` on coretec-contacts and then you can use `Sacco ob = dataSnapshot.getvalue(Sacco.class);` in it.

Comment: Thank you that worked.
Do you also know how I can get the current item title on the onItemClick listener for the firebase adapter?

Comment: Nice to know it worked. Do mark it as the solution for letting others know for community help. 
You can use `getItem()` for any item in adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get reference to your node:

```
DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Your Node Name");
```