# No setter/field for Vehicle Type found on class com.potenza_pvt_ltd.AAPS.TruckDetailsActivity

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have seen others ask this question but it seems to me that I have done all the things that are required and I'm still not getting it to work. I am getting the No setter/field for Vehicle Type found on class 
No setter/field for Time of Arrival found on class 
No setter/field for Driver Number found on class 
No setter/field for Vehicle Number found on class 
No setter/field for Time of Departure found on class 
No setter/field for Partial Amount Paid found on class

```
public class TruckDetailsActivity {
        //name and address string
    @JsonProperty("Transporter")
        private String Transporter;
    @JsonProperty("Driver Name")
    private String DriverName;

    public void setVehicleType(String vehicleType) {
        VehicleType = vehicleType;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Driver Number")
        private String DriverNumber;
    @JsonProperty("Vehicle Number")
        private String VehicleNumber;
    @JsonProperty("Date")
        private String Date;
    @JsonProperty("aps")
        private String aps;
    @JsonProperty("email")
    private String email;
    private String key;
    @JsonProperty("Time of Arrival")
    private String TimeofArrival;
    @JsonProperty("Cost")
    private String Cost;
    @JsonProperty("Time of Departure")
    private String TimeofDeparture;
    @JsonProperty("Partial Amount Paid")
    private String PartialAmountPaid;
    @JsonProperty("Vehicle Type")
    private String VehicleType;

    @JsonProperty("Cash Handover")
    private String CashHandover;

    @JsonProperty("Operator")
    private String Operator;
    public TruckDetailsActivity() {

            /*Blank default constructor essential for Firebase*/
        }
    public TruckDetailsActivity(String a){

    }
    public TruckDetailsActivity(String k, String s, String index, String index1, String index2, String index3) {
        this.key=k;
        email=s;
        Transporter =index;
        DriverNumber =index1;
        Date =index2;
        aps =index3;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Key")
    public String getKey(){
        return this.key;
    }
    public void setKey(String key){
        this.key=key;
    }
    //Getters and setters
    public String getTransporter() {
            return this.Transporter;
        }
    public void setTransporter(String contractorname) {
            this.Transporter = contractorname;
        }

    public String getDriverName() {
            return this.DriverName;
        }

    public void setDriverName(String driverName) {
        this.DriverName = driverName;
    }
    public String getDriverNumber() {
            return this.DriverNumber;
        }
    public String getVehicleNumber() {
            return this.VehicleNumber;
        }

    public String getDate() {
            return this.Date;
        }


    public void setDate(String date) {
            this.Date = date;
        }


    public String getAps() {
        return this.aps;
    }

    public void setAps(String aps) {
        this.aps = aps;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email){this.email=email;}

    public String getTimeofArrival() {
        return this.TimeofArrival;
    }


    public String getCost() {
        return this.Cost;
    }

    public void setCost(String T) {
        this.Cost = T;
    }

    public String getTimeofDeparture() {
        return TimeofDeparture;
    }


    public String getPartialAmountPaid() {
        return PartialAmountPaid;
    }


    public String getVehicleType() {
        return VehicleType;
    }


    public String getCashHandover() {
        return CashHandover;
    }

    public void setCashHandover(String cashHandover) {
        CashHandover = cashHandover;
    }


    public String getOperator() {
        return Operator;
    }

    public void setOperator(String operator){this.Operator=operator;}

This is my Java file from where i call the above class.

    Query queryRef = reference.child("users").child("data").orderByChild(sort);
        queryRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    TruckDetailsActivity post = ds.getValue(TruckDetailsActivity.class);
                    post.setKey(ds.getKey());
                    Log.d("post", post.getKey());
                    TruckDetailsActivity obj = new TruckDetailsActivity(post.getKey(), post.getEmail(), post.getTransporter(), post.getDriverNumber(), post.getDate(), post.getAps());
                    list.add(index, obj);
                    Log.d("list", String.valueOf(list.get(index)));
                    index++;
                }
                mAdapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(list);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Log.d("count of list", String.valueOf(mAdapter.getItemCount()));
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Gradle Build

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.potenza_pvt_ltd.AAPS"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.0'
    //compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.github.brnunes:swipeablerecyclerview:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.0.0'
    compile files('libs/poi-3.14-20160307.jar')
    compile files('libs/joda-time-2.9.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-annotations-2.2.3.jar')
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: make the fields public instead of private.

Comment: Your code includes classes from the new SDK, ex: `DatabaseError`.  The `@JsonProperty` is a Jackson annotation.  Jackson was used in the legacy SDK (2.x.x) but not the new SDK (9.x.x).  Are you including both SDKs in your dependencies?  Can you post your app build.gradle?

Comment: i have added the build.gradle. Please check.

Comment: check this --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38572640/no-setter-field-for-while-trying-to-populate-a-listview-on-firebase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you created a Firebase database using a previous version of your app that was built using the legacy (2.x.x) SDK.  The legacy SDK uses Jackson for converting to/from JSON.  You used the Jackson annotation `@JsonProperty` and specified names containing spaces.

You have now upgraded your app to use the new SDK, which does not use Jackson and instead expects JavaBean getter/setter naming conventions for conversion of POJO classes to/from JSON.  This creates a problem with your database fields whose names have spaces in them, such as "Driver Number".

The only solution I know of is to go to the Firebase console and export your database to a JSON file, edit it manually to replace the field names that contain spaces, then import back into Firebase.  The export/import actions are available in the overflow menu icon (three vertical dots) at the upper right corner of the Firebase console database tab.